# Javascript ".call" don't understand

Tags: javascript

I don't get the difference between the last 2 lines, specifically the difference between myFunc.call and myFunc.  Can someone please explain to me? I'd really appreciate it.

```
var myObject = {
length: 400,
};

function myFunc () {
return console.log(this.length);

}

myFunc.call(myObject); // equals 400
myFunc(myObject); // equals zero
```

Comment: Read up on how the `this` context works in JavaScript.

Comment: my question relates more to how .call works and not this. I understand the last line and how it works with this.

Comment: It is very much related to `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `call` method is used to specify a context for the function, the same as if the function was a member of the object, and was called as a method:

```
var myObject = {
  length: 400,
  myFunc: function () {
    return console.log(this.length);
  }
};

myObject.myFunc(); // equals 400
```

Answer (score 2):

`.call()` allows you to call a function while specifying what `this` will refer to inside the function. Calling it without `.call` uses the current value of `this`.

In your example, `myFunc.call(myObject)` runs `myFunc` with `myObject` as `this`, which allows `this.length` to actually refer to something.